# Get value of attribute using CSS Selectors with BeutifulSoup

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am web-scraping with `Python` and using `BeutifulSoup` library

I have `HTML` markup like this:

```
<tr class="deals" data-url="www.example2.com">
<span class="hotel-name">
<a href="www.example2.com"></a>
</span>
</tr>
<tr class="deals" data-url="www.example3.com">
<span class="hotel-name">
<a href="www.example3.com"></a>
</span>
</tr>
```

I want to get the `data-url` or the `href` value in all `<tr>`s. Better If I can get `href` value

Here is a little snippet of my relevant code:

```
main_url =  "http://localhost/test.htm"
page  = requests.get(main_url).text
soup_expatistan = BeautifulSoup(page)

print (soup_expatistan.select("tr.deals").data-url)
# or  print (soup_expatistan.select("tr.deals").["data-url"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tr.deals span.hotel-name a` CSS Selector to get to the link:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<tr class="deals" data-url="www.example.com">
<span class="hotel-name">
<a href="wwwexample2.com"></a>
</span>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup.select('tr.deals span.hotel-name a')[0]['href'])
```

Prints:

```
wwwexample2.com
```

If you have multiple links, iterate over them:

```
for link in soup.select('tr.deals span.hotel-name a'):
    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: This works ... Actually I have multiple `<tr>`s in my Markup ... How do I iterate over all `tr`s and find the `a` link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806808/charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-xae-while-scraping-a-webpage