# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' While Scraping a Webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web-scraping with `Python` using `BeautifulSoap`
I am getting this error

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 69: character maps to <undefined>
```

when scraping a webpage

This is my `Python`

```
hotel = BeautifulSoup(state.)
print (hotel.select("div.details.cf span.hotel-name a"))
# Tried:  print (hotel.select("div.details.cf span.hotel-name a")).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Looks like this may be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4197411/2372812. You need to set the codec much earlier than in your provided `# Tried:` line.

Comment: I did but no difference

Answer (score 1):

We usually encounter this problem here when we are trying to `.encode()` an already encoded byte string. So you might try to decode it first as in

```
html = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
unicode_str = html.decode(<source encoding>)
encoded_str = unicode_str.encode("utf8")
```

As an example:

```
html = '\xae'
encoded_str = html.encode("utf8")
```

Fails with

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

While:

```
html = '\xae'
decoded_str = html.decode("windows-1252")
encoded_str = decoded_str.encode("utf8")
print encoded_str
®
```

Succeeds without error. Do note that "windows-1252" is something I used as an *example*. I got this from chardet and it had 0.5 confidence that it is right! (well, as given with a 1-character-length string, what do you expect) You should change that to the encoding of the byte string returned from `.urlopen().read()` to what applies to the content you retrieved.

Comment: You noted you have to use decode('latin-1') not encode('latin-1').

Comment: I've changed my answer. Hope it helps.